# Fusion Table values not returned correctly

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I want to get the co-ordinates(latitude-longitude) of states in a country 
I tried with google fusion table 
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=420419#rows:id=1
but when I try to fetch the data result is incorrect

code that I tried is here:

```js
var map = null;
var infoWindow = null;
var geoXml = null;
var geoXmlDoc = null;
var myLatLng = null;
var myOptions = null;
var mapCenter = null;
var geocodeTheCountry = true;
var gpolygons = [];

// Fusion Table data ID
var FT_TableID = "19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA"; // 420419;
//var CountryName = "Saudi Arabia";
var CountryName = "India";
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
});

function createSidebar() {
    // set the query using the parameters
    var FT_Query2 = "SELECT 'name_0', 'name_1', 'kml_4326','json_4326'  FROM " + FT_TableID + " WHERE name_0 = '" + CountryName + "' ORDER by 'name_1'";
    var queryText = encodeURIComponent(FT_Query2);
    // alert("createSidebar query="+FT_Query2);
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);

    //set the callback function
    query.send(getData);
}

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(createSidebar);

var FTresponse = null;

myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808, -122.0838851);
// these set the initial center, zoom and maptype for the map 
// if it is not specified in the query string
var lat = 37.422104808;
var lng = -122.0838851;
var zoom = 18;
var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) {
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
}
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
//define callback function, this is called when the results are returned
function getData(response) {
    if (!response) {
        alert('no response');
        return;
    }
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    FTresponse = response;
    //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
    //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
    numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
    numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

    fusiontabledata = "<table>";
    fusiontabledata += "<th>Region</th>";
    //fusiontabledata += "<th>" + response.getDataTable().getColumnLabel(1) + "</th>";
    //   }
    fusiontabledata += "<tr></tr><tr>";

    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
     
        fusiontabledata += "<td><div onclick='javascript:myFTclick(" + i + ");getGeocodeList(" + response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 4) + ")'>" + response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1) + "</div></td>";
        //    }
        fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
    }
    fusiontabledata += "</table>";
    //display the results on the page
    document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;
}

function infoWindowContent(name, description) {
    content = '<div><h3>' + name +
            '</h3><div>' + description + '</div></div>';
    return content;
}

function myFTclick(row) {
    var description = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row, 0);
    var name = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row, 1);
    if (!gpolygons[row]) {
        var kml = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row, 2);
        // create a geoXml3 parser for the click handlers
        var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
            map: map,
            zoom: false,
            infoWindow: infoWindow,
            singleInfoWindow: true
        });

        geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark>" + kml + "</Placemark>");
        geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].setMap(null);
        gpolygons[row] = geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds.getCenter();
    }
    var position = gpolygons[row];
    if (!infoWindow)
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    infoWindow.setOptions({
        content: infoWindowContent(name, description),
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 2),
        position: position
    });
    infoWindow.open(map);
}

function getGeocodeList(row) {
    alert(row.coordinates);   
}

function initialize() {
    myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: maptype
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder && geocodeTheCountry) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': CountryName + " Country"
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    alert("No results found");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

    var FT_Query = "SELECT 'kml_4326' FROM " + FT_TableID + " WHERE 'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "';";
    var FT_Options = {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        query: {
            from: FT_TableID,
            select: 'kml_4326',
            where: "'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "';"
        },
        styles: [{
                polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor: "green",
                    fillOpacity: 0.05
                }
            }]
    };
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FT_Options);
    layer.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function (event) {
        infoWindow.close();
        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent(event.row.name_1.value, event.row.name_0.value));
        infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infoWindow.open(map);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

inside the getGeocodeList function values listed are not correct

Comment: I get a javascript error with your code: `Uncaught Error: Invalid column index 4. Should be an integer in the range [0-3].`

Answer (score 1):

I get a javascript error with your code: `Uncaught Error: Invalid column index 4. Should be an integer in the range [0-3].`  The visualization query only has 4 members, 0-3; you are asking for member 4.  Change:

```
getGeocodeList(" + response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 4) + ")'>"
```

to:

```
getGeocodeList(" + response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3) + ")'>"
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1ukcccqa/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var infoWindow = null;
var geoXml = null;
var geoXmlDoc = null;
var myLatLng = null;
var myOptions = null;
var mapCenter = null;
var geocodeTheCountry = true;
var gpolygons = [];

// Fusion Table data ID
var FT_TableID = "19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA"; // 420419;
var CountryName = "India";
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
});

function createSidebar() {
  // set the query using the parameters
  var FT_Query2 = "SELECT 'name_0', 'name_1', 'kml_4326','json_4326'  FROM " + FT_TableID + " WHERE name_0 = '" + CountryName + "' ORDER by 'name_1'";
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(FT_Query2);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);
  //set the callback function
  query.send(getData);
}

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(createSidebar);

var FTresponse = null;

myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808, -122.0838851);
// these set the initial center, zoom and maptype for the map 
// if it is not specified in the query string
var lat = 37.422104808;
var lng = -122.0838851;
var zoom = 18;
var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) {
  myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
}
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
//define callback function, this is called when the results are returned
function getData(response) {
  if (!response) {
    alert('no response');
    return;
  }
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

  fusiontabledata = "<table>";
  fusiontabledata += "<th>Region</th>";
  fusiontabledata += "<tr></tr><tr>";

  for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    fusiontabledata += "<td><div onclick='javascript:myFTclick(" + i + "); getGeocodeList(" + response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3) + ")'>" + response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1) + "</div></td>";
    fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  fusiontabledata += "</table>";
  //display the results on the page
  document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;
}

function infoWindowContent(name, description) {
  content = '<div><h3>' + name +
    '</h3><div>' + description + '</div></div>';
  return content;
}

function myFTclick(row) {
  var description = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row, 0);
  var name = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row, 1);
  if (!gpolygons[row]) {
    var kml = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row, 2);
    // create a geoXml3 parser for the click handlers
    var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
      map: map,
      zoom: false,
      infoWindow: infoWindow,
      singleInfoWindow: true
    });

    geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark>" + kml + "</Placemark>");
    geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].setMap(null);
    gpolygons[row] = geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds.getCenter();
  }
  var position = gpolygons[row];
  if (!infoWindow)
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
  infoWindow.setOptions({
    content: infoWindowContent(name, description),
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 2),
    position: position
  });
  infoWindow.open(map);
}

function getGeocodeList(row) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = row.coordinates;
}

function initialize() {
  myOptions = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: maptype
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  if (geocoder && geocodeTheCountry) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': CountryName + " Country"
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  var FT_Query = "SELECT 'kml_4326' FROM " + FT_TableID + " WHERE 'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "';";
  var FT_Options = {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    query: {
      from: FT_TableID,
      select: 'kml_4326',
      where: "'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "';"
    },
    styles: [{
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: "green",
        fillOpacity: 0.05
      }
    }]
  };
  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FT_Options);
  layer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(event) {
    infoWindow.close();
    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent(event.row.name_1.value, event.row.name_0.value));
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: problem is the negative values in latitude and longitude are not getting in the result

Comment: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=420419#rows:id=1 result is not same as that in the table

Comment: Point to whatever table you want, I just based my example on the code you provided.

Comment: problem is the negative values in latitude and longitude are not getting in the result ?

Comment: You mean the two columns `kml_4326` and `json_4326` are not consistent?  Actually for India, there shouldn't be any negative latitudes or longitudes.